# Can't create a new OpenSSL key

Tags: php, windows, openssl, xampp

I want to learn OpenSSL but I'm just getting `boolean false` when I am trying to use this code:

```
$config = array('private_key_bits' => 512);
$privKey = openssl_pkey_new($config);

var_dump($privKey);
```

The OpenSSL extension is activated on my server. Have I missed something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [openssl_error_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-error-string.php) after your *openssl_** function is called:

```
while($e = openssl_error_string() ) {
    print_r($e."\n");
}
```

On my Windows it outputs:

```
error:02001003:system library:fopen:No such process
error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file
error:0E064002:configuration file routines:CONF_load:system lib
error:02001003:system library:fopen:No such process
error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file
error:0E064002:configuration file routines:CONF_load:system lib
```

See the first note at this function [openssl_pkey_new()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-pkey-new.php):

> Note: You need to have a valid openssl.cnf installed for this function
>   to operate correctly. See the notes under the installation section for
>   more information.

Comment: Ah! So that's why I got these error messages. Thanks :)

Comment: Ok, but and now? I got this error, and I'm stop...